# get value from Dynamically add multiple spinner in android?

Tags: android

How to get value to dynamically add multiple spinner where spinner id is same.i used 'String spin = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();' but i get all time last spinner value.Plz help me?

Comment: `add multiple spinner with a same id` mean ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: for(int i =0;i<10;i++){ View v = LayoutInflater.from(AssetCodingDetails.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_asset_coding_label, null);
spinner_status = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_status);
status_list.add("" + snapshot.getValue());// getting data
}ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.spinner_item,status_list;
spinner_status.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Use RecyclerView with adapter

Comment: i want add multiple spinner at run time and on submit button get data all spinner but i get last spinner value this is my problem.

Comment: you initialize single spinner object 10 time in for loop and set adapter out side loop.

Comment: how to use recycler view with different spinner

Comment: You should bind your adapter outside for loop

Comment: but how to add different value in spinner

Answer (score 0):

you can create array list of spinner

```
ArrayList<Spinner> listSpinner = new ArrayList<>();
listSpinner.add(spinner1);
listSpinner.add(spinner2);
listSpinner.add(spinner3);

for(int i=0;i<listSpinner.size();i++){
  String p1 = listSpinner.get(i).getSelectedItem();
}
```

Comment: can you share some example or links for this@Bhupat Bheda

Answer (score 0):

get different value for all spinner out side for loop and store it in arraylist.

```
ArrayList<Spinner> listSpinner = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> s‌​tatus_list = new ArrayList<>();
    status_data.add("" + snapshot.getValue());// getting data
    s‌​tatus_list.add(status_data);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(AssetCodingDetails.this).inflate(R.layou‌​t.custom_asset_codin‌​g_label, null);
        Spinner spinner_status = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_status);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, s‌​tatus_list.get(i));
        spinner_status.setAdapter(adapter);
        listSpinner.add(spinner_status);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<listSpinner.size();i++){
        String p1 = listSpinner.get(i).getSelectedItem().toString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Avani Paneliya but please tell me how to get value in different different item.like that:
String first = listSpinner.get(i);
String Second= listSpinner.get(i);
but it returns all value